# Rewind request body stream

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, owin, owin-middleware

I am re-implementing a request logger as Owin Middleware which logs the request url and body of all incoming requests. **I am able to read the body, but if I do the body parameter in my controller is null.**

I'm guessing it's null because the stream position is at the end so there is nothing left to read when it tries to deserialize the body. I had a similar issue in a previous version of Web API but was able to set the Stream position back to 0. This particular stream throws a `This stream does not support seek operations` exception.

In the most recent version of Web API 2.0 I could call `Request.HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync()`inside my request logger, and the body would still arrive to the controller in tact.

**How can I rewind the stream after reading it?**

or

**How can I read the request body without consuming it?**

```
public class RequestLoggerMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    public RequestLoggerMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next)
        : base(next)
    {
    }

    public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => {
            string body = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEnd();
            // log body

            context.Request.Body.Position = 0; // cannot set stream position back to 0
            Console.WriteLine(context.Request.Body.CanSeek); // prints false
            this.Next.Invoke(context);
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SampleController : ApiController 
{
    public void Post(ModelClass body)
    {
        // body is now null if the middleware reads it
    }
}
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Just found one solution. Replacing the original stream with a **new stream** containing the data.

```
    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => {
            string body = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEnd();
            // log body

            byte[] requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body);
            context.Request.Body = new MemoryStream(requestData);
            await this.Next.Invoke(context);
        });
    }
```

If you are dealing with larger amounts of data, I'm sure a `FileStream` would also work as the replacement.

Comment: Another alternative:

Stream anotherStream = new MemoryStream();
context.Request.Body.CopyToAsync(anotherStream);

Comment: In ASP.NET Core (where the invoke method would have the following signature `async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)`) you can do the following to get a buffered stream which allows you to seek and read it multiple times; `context.Request.EnableRewind()` (HttpRequest extension method found in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.BufferingHelper`).

Comment: @jfiskvik Your input was extremely helpful for me, It helped me rewind my stream after some processing that happened in my MiddleWare

Comment: When using `.NET Core 3.1` (and up) you can use `context.Request.EnableBuffering()` (instead of `context.Request.EnableRewind()` per the answer of @jfiskvik) found in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http`. This enables me to reset the body like so: `context.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`.

Comment: WARNING: 

This answer is dangerous:
- The `Task` result from `Next.Invoke()` is not used (or awaited)
- `Task.Run` will run the continuation in a thread-pool thread - no `SynchronizationContext` and so `HttpContext.Current` will not be set correctly. 

Under load, this code will do BAD things.

Comment: @eddiewould I added an await to the Next.Invoke().

Answer (score 14):

Here's a small improvement to the first answer by Despertar, which helped me a lot, but I ran into an issue when working with **binary data.** The intermediate step of extracting the stream into a string and then putting it back into a byte array using `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body)` messes up the binary content (the contents will change unless it is an UTF8 encoded string). Here's my fix using `Stream.CopyTo()`:

```
    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        // read out body (wait for all bytes)
        using (var streamCopy = new MemoryStream())
        {
            context.Request.Body.CopyTo(streamCopy);
            streamCopy.Position = 0; // rewind

            string body = new StreamReader(streamCopy).ReadToEnd();
            // log body

            streamCopy.Position = 0; // rewind again
            context.Request.Body = streamCopy; // put back in place for downstream handlers

            await this.Next.Invoke(context);
        }
    }
```

Also, `MemoryStream` is nice because you can check the stream's length before logging the full body (which is something I don't want to do in case someone uploads a huge file).

Comment: I have tried this code, but it is throwing an excepting when I tried to read the second time.

Comment: On which line does the exception occur?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same need and solved the issue by doing the below:

In Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
    });
    [...]
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app..)
{
   app.UseWhen(
      ab => ab.UseMiddleware<EnableRequestBodyBufferingMiddleware>()
   );
}
```

Create a new file for your middleware class. In your middleware:

```
public class EnableRequestBodyBufferingMiddleware
{
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public EnableRequestBodyBufferingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) =>
            _next = next;

        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            Stream originalBody = context.Response.Body;
            try
            {
                using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    context.Request.EnableBuffering();

                    context.Request.Body.CopyTo(memStream);
                    memStream.Position = 0; // rewind

                    string body = new StreamReader(memStream).ReadToEnd();

                    memStream.Position = 0; // rewind again
                    context.Request.Body = memStream; // put back in place for downstream handlers

                    await _next(context);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Response.Body = originalBody;
            }
        }
}
```

In your controller:

```
[HttpPost()]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetRequestBodyEndpoint([FromBody]YourModelObject myObj)
{
    HttpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
    var reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Request.Body);
    var originalRequest = await reader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    [...]
}
```

Here, the `originalRequest` holds the actual request sent to my POST endpoint. Adding it here for my future reference.

Answer (score -3):

I know this is old, but just to help anyone that comes across this.
You need to seek on the stream: `context.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

Comment: Same as `Body.Position = 0`, this throws a `NotSupportedException` with the message `This stream does not support seek operations`. Also the `Body.CanSeek` property returns false.