# How to read ASP.NET Core Response.Body?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-middleware

I've been struggling to get the `Response.Body` property from an ASP.NET Core action and the only solution I've been able to identify seems sub-optimal.  The solution requires swapping out `Response.Body` with a `MemoryStream` while reading the stream into a string variable, then swapping it back before sending to the client.  In the examples below, I'm trying to get the `Response.Body` value in a custom middleware class.  `Response.Body` is a *set* only property in ASP.NET Core for some reason?  Am I just missing something here, or is this an oversight/bug/design issue?  Is there a better way to read `Response.Body`?

**Current (sub-optimal) solution:**

```
public class MyMiddleWare
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyMiddleWare(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        using (var swapStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var originalResponseBody = context.Response.Body;

            context.Response.Body = swapStream;

            await _next(context);

            swapStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string responseBody = new StreamReader(swapStream).ReadToEnd();
            swapStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            await swapStream.CopyToAsync(originalResponseBody);
            context.Response.Body = originalResponseBody;
        }
    }
}
```

**Attempted solution using EnableRewind():**
This only works for `Request.Body`, not `Response.Body`.  This results in reading an empty string from `Response.Body` rather than the actual response body contents.

*Startup.cs*

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationLifetime appLifeTime)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.Use(async (context, next) => {
        context.Request.EnableRewind();
        await next();
    });

    app.UseMyMiddleWare();

    app.UseMvc();

    // Dispose of Autofac container on application stop
    appLifeTime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => this.ApplicationContainer.Dispose());
}
```

*MyMiddleWare.cs*

```
public class MyMiddleWare
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public MyMiddleWare(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        await _next(context);
        string responseBody = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEnd(); //responseBody is ""
        context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is by design.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

In my original response I had totally misread the question and thought the poster was asking how to read the `Request.Body` But he had asked how to read the `Response.Body`.   I'm leaving my original answer to preserve history but also updating it to show how I would answer the question once reading it correctly.

**Original Answer**

If you want a buffered stream that supports reading multiple times you need to set

```
   context.Request.EnableRewind()
```

Ideally do this early in the middleware before anything needs to read the body.

So for example you could place the following code in the beginning of the `Configure` method of the Startup.cs file:

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) => {
            context.Request.EnableRewind();
            await next();
        });
```

Prior to enabling Rewind the stream associated with the `Request.Body` is a forward only stream that doesn't support seeking or reading the stream a second time.  This was done to make the default configuration of request handling as lightweight and performant as possible.  But once you enable rewind the stream is upgrade to a stream that supports seeking and reading multiple times.  You can observe this "upgrade" by setting a breakpoint just before and just after the call to `EnableRewind` and observing the `Request.Body` properties.  So for example `Request.Body.CanSeek` will change from `false` to `true`.

*update*: Starting in ASP.NET Core 2.1 `Request.EnableBuffering()` is available which upgrades the `Request.Body` to a `FileBufferingReadStream` just like `Request.EnableRewind()` and since `Request.EnableBuffering()` is in a public namespace rather than an internal one it should be preferred over EnableRewind().  (Thanks to @ArjanEinbu for pointing out)

Then to read the body stream you could for example do this:

```
   string bodyContent = new StreamReader(Request.Body).ReadToEnd();
```

Don't wrap the `StreamReader` creation in a using statement though or it will close the underlying body stream at the conclusion of the using block and code later in the request lifecycle wont be able to read the body.

Also just to be safe, it might be a good idea to follow the above line of code that reads the body content with this line of code to reset the body's stream position back to 0.

```
request.Body.Position = 0;
```

That way any code later in the request lifecycle will find the request.Body in a state just like it hasn't been read yet.

**Updated Answer**

Sorry I originally misread your question. The concept of upgrading the associated stream to be a buffered stream still applies. However you do have to do it manually, I'm unaware of any built in .Net Core functionality that lets you read the response stream once written in the way that `EnableRewind()` lets a developer reread the request stream after it's been read.

Your "hacky" approach is likely totally appropriate. You are basically converting a stream that can't seek to one that can.  At the end of the day the `Response.Body` stream has to get swapped out with a stream that is buffered and supports seeking.  Here is another take on middleware to do that but you will notice it's quite similar to your approach.  I did however choose to use a finally block as added protection for putting the original stream back on the `Response.Body` and I used the `Position` property of the stream rather than the `Seek` method since the syntax is a bit simpler but the effect is no different than your approach.

```
public class ResponseRewindMiddleware 
{
        private readonly RequestDelegate next;

        public ResponseRewindMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) {
            this.next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context) {

            Stream originalBody = context.Response.Body;

            try {
                using (var memStream = new MemoryStream()) {
                    context.Response.Body = memStream;

                    await next(context);

                    memStream.Position = 0;
                    string responseBody = new StreamReader(memStream).ReadToEnd();

                    memStream.Position = 0;
                    await memStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody);
                }

            } finally {
                context.Response.Body = originalBody;
            }

        } 
}
```

Comment: So I found this documentation on EnableRewind(): [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.internal.bufferinghelper), but it doesn't really give much indication of how it works... can you elaborate on how I could change my code to utilize EnableRewind?

Comment: Sure, I will add more to my answer.  I'm using it and it works great.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information @Ron C, I tried the solution that you suggested, and while I can see that the CanRead and CanSeek properties have been updated to true, the reader simple reads an empty string back to the bodyContent variable.  I can see in PostMan that an actual full response body is returned to the client.  I'll update my question to reflect my approach using EnableRewind().

Comment: @woogy My Bad!  I totally misread your question.  I thought you wanted to read the request Body.  But you asked how to read the *response* body.  The concept of upgrading the associated steam to be a buffered steam still applies but I think you would have to do it manually.  Your "hacky" approach is likely totally appropriate. You are basically converting a stream that can't seek to one that can.

Comment: I get exceptions if I refesh a page with cached CSS, specifically "System.InvalidOperationException: Write to non-body 304 response."  A hack around this might involve checking for 304s, but is there a better more general work around?

Comment: Further: I can check context.Response.ContentLength for null and zero value conditions and shortcut out with "await _next(context); return;".  This stops me logging null or empty responses, and stops the 304 exception when refreshing a page.  This could be a bad approach though, please shoot it down if it is wrong.

Comment: I'm unclear on the scenario that produces the error.  Can you elaborate on what "refesh a page with cached CSS" means?  The page request is one request through the middleware, and if that page loads a css file then that will be a second request through the middleware.  What is the css cached by (the browser or the server?) If the server, then via what mechanism?  This may be too much for comments and I'd be happy to move the conversation to Stackoverflow chat but am unclear how to do that (never done it before).

Comment: To replicate, set up a simple HelloWorld page that links to a CSS stylesheet (css file), browse to the page, the CSS is loaded, refresh with F5, and the css file is not re-sent.  In my logs I was seeing an exception thrown because I was attempting to write to the body of a response that should have no body.  Also, have posted class to public [github](https://github.com/Hiblet/LogRequestAndResponseMiddleware).  The code checks that the response body has size before attempting to copy back to the original body.

Comment: @RonC (see above plus...) Caching is done by the browser, the CSS is sent once, and an F5 refresh re-pulls the page, but not the cached static files. The link in an HTML file for CSS file causes a new HTTP request to pull that file, so one page request can trigger multiple underlying sub-requests.  This is why minifying and aggregating static files is useful, as it sends less data, and uses less requests.  Happy to chat if you like, UK timezone.

Comment: @RonC: I found `context.Request.EnableBuffering()`. Would that be a more correct/up-to-date solution?

Comment: @ ArjanEinbu Thanks for pointing out `context.Request.EnableBuffering()` which is available starting in ASP.NET Core 2.1.  EnableBuffering() does indeed upgrade the request body to a `FileBufferingReadStream` just like `Request.EnableRewind()` and since it's in a public namespace rather than an internal one it should be preferred over EnableRewind().  Note that this is for the _request_ object and the question is regarding the _response_ object.  I will update my original answer to include this info.

Comment: Can someone explain why it still works withouth the finally block? I mean it is not needed to set the original body to context body: context.Response.Body = originalBody; and it works the same. It looks like no matter what you do, the "original" body will be returned so one thing you must do just copy your's memory stream to "original" stream;

Comment: Sure it will still “work” without the finally in that you can read the response but if you don’t have the finally then down stream code will have a response stream that may be in a different state then they expected.  Such bugs when they occur are often very hard to track down.  It’s best practice for things like this to leave the response stream the way you found it unless you have a very specific reason to do otherwise.  The finally ensures we leave things the way we found them. We reconnect the original stream back to the response object.

Comment: @RonC Is this possible to generate custom response if  **next(context)** throw an exception. Actually i am getting empty response body on that.

Comment: @MuhammadAzim sure, provided you wrap the call in a try catch block.  For example in the catch you could set `context.Response.StatusCode` and call `await context.Response.WriteAsync(errorMessage)`.  If you need additional help on the topic it's best to ask a separate question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @RonC I have post new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879170/getting-empty-response-on-asp-net-core-middleware-on-exception)

Comment: Thank you @RonC - Just showing my appreciation for your post!

Comment: Does anyone know if its possible to know what the length of the response body is without streaming it into memory? I'd like to avoid that memory hit. In my middleware I'm only logging the response if it's smaller than 80kb.

Comment: I don’t think you can get the length without streaming it because it’s a stream and streams go until they don’t ;-). But you could choose to log only the first 80kb of the stream if you so choose.  I actually only log the first X bytes myself in my actual use case.

Comment: I should add that if you only log the first X bytes you don’t have to read the rest of the steam, just read the bytes you want to log.

Comment: This solution works very well when you return serialized data, but when you return a `File ` object, it only works for small files. I tried with files smaller than 10mb and bigger than 200mb. For the small files everything is ok, but for the bigger files, the downloaded file has 0kb. Does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: @rbasniak In my example I use a MemoryStream, so it may be that for large files you need to use a different stream type that is backed by disk.  At least that's the first thing I'd try.

Comment: @RonC Ok, thanks for the idea that would be a possible solution.

Answer (score 19):

## .NET 6.0+ Solution

In ASP.NET Core 6.0+ consider using a built-in extensions:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
//...
builder.Services.AddHttpLogging(options => // <--- Setup logging
{
    // Specify all that you need here:
    options.LoggingFields = HttpLoggingFields.RequestHeaders |
                            HttpLoggingFields.RequestBody |
                            HttpLoggingFields.ResponseHeaders |
                            HttpLoggingFields.ResponseBody;
});
//...
var app = builder.Build();
//...
app.UseHttpLogging(); // <--- Add logging to pipeline
//...
app.Run();
```

Comment: By default is is logging to Console. How do I configure that , these logs should be saved to my SQL DB ?

Comment: @Roushan you should setup logging providers for this purpose: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging-providers
But I prefer to use Serilog's Sink's for logging.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to log request/response together in the middleware..

Comment: @Yiping why do you need middleware?

Comment: to Log the same trip request/response body together?

Comment: For anyone not seeing the expected logs after adding the middleware: don't forget to add `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware": "Information"` to your `appsettings.json`.

Comment: This in no way answers the question.

Answer (score 15):

You can use a [middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) 
in the request pipeline, in order to log request and responses.

However is increased the hazard of `memory leak`, due to the facth that:
1. Streams,
2. Setting Byte Buffers and 
3. String conversions

can end up to [Large Object Heap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap) (in case the body of request or response is larger than 85,000 bytes). This increases the hazard of memory leak in your application.
 In order to avoid LOH, memory streams can be replaced by [Recyclable Memory stream](http://www.philosophicalgeek.com/2015/02/06/announcing-microsoft-io-recycablememorystream/) using the relevant [library](https://github.com/Microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream).

An implementation that uses Recyclable memory streams:

```
public class RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly RecyclableMemoryStreamManager _recyclableMemoryStreamManager;
    private const int ReadChunkBufferLength = 4096;

    public RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = loggerFactory
            .CreateLogger<RequestResponseLoggingMiddleware>();
        _recyclableMemoryStreamManager = new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager();
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        LogRequest(context.Request);
        await LogResponseAsync(context);
    }

    private void LogRequest(HttpRequest request)
    {
        request.EnableRewind();
        using (var requestStream = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream())
        {
            request.Body.CopyTo(requestStream);
            _logger.LogInformation($"Http Request Information:{Environment.NewLine}" +
                                   $"Schema:{request.Scheme} " +
                                   $"Host: {request.Host} " +
                                   $"Path: {request.Path} " +
                                   $"QueryString: {request.QueryString} " +
                                   $"Request Body: {ReadStreamInChunks(requestStream)}");
        }
    }

    private async Task LogResponseAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var originalBody = context.Response.Body;
        using (var responseStream = _recyclableMemoryStreamManager.GetStream())
        {
            context.Response.Body = responseStream;
            await _next.Invoke(context);
            await responseStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody);
            _logger.LogInformation($"Http Response Information:{Environment.NewLine}" +
                                   $"Schema:{context.Request.Scheme} " +
                                   $"Host: {context.Request.Host} " +
                                   $"Path: {context.Request.Path} " +
                                   $"QueryString: {context.Request.QueryString} " +
                                   $"Response Body: {ReadStreamInChunks(responseStream)}");
        }

        context.Response.Body = originalBody;
    }

    private static string ReadStreamInChunks(Stream stream)
    {
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        string result;
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            var readChunk = new char[ReadChunkBufferLength];
            int readChunkLength;
            //do while: is useful for the last iteration in case readChunkLength < chunkLength
            do
            {
                readChunkLength = reader.ReadBlock(readChunk, 0, ReadChunkBufferLength);
                textWriter.Write(readChunk, 0, readChunkLength);
            } while (readChunkLength > 0);

            result = textWriter.ToString();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

NB. The hazard of LOH is not fully eradicate due to `textWriter.ToString()` on the other hand you can use a logging client library that supports structured logging (ie. Serilog) and inject the instance of a Recyclable Memory Stream.

Comment: I guess `request.Body.Position = 0` is required right after you logged the request. Otherwise, you will get empty body exception.

Comment: `await responseStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody);` did not copy in my case. I used `responseStream.WriteTo(originalBody);`

Comment: Seems that for `await responseStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody);` to work correctly one needs to first do `responseStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

Answer (score 15):

[@RonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43404745/7011003) works for the most part. But I wanted to add this. It seems that ASP.NET Core does not like to present the web contents directly from the memory stream (unless it's a simple string and not a whole HTML page). I spent hours trying to figure this one out, so I wanted to post it here so that other people wouldn't waste their time trying to figure this one out as I did.

Here is the little modification of @RonC's answer about the response part:

```cs
public class ResponseBufferMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ResponseBufferMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Store the original body stream for restoring the response body back to its original stream
        var originalBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

        // Create new memory stream for reading the response; Response body streams are write-only, therefore memory stream is needed here to read
        await using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        context.Response.Body = memoryStream;

        // Call the next middleware
        await _next(context);

        // Set stream pointer position to 0 before reading
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // Read the body from the stream
        var responseBodyText = await new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEndAsync();

        // Reset the position to 0 after reading
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // Do this last, that way you can ensure that the end results end up in the response.
        // (This resulting response may come either from the redirected route or other special routes if you have any redirection/re-execution involved in the middleware.)
        // This is very necessary. ASP.NET doesn't seem to like presenting the contents from the memory stream.
        // Therefore, the original stream provided by the ASP.NET Core engine needs to be swapped back.
        // Then write back from the previous memory stream to this original stream.
        // (The content is written in the memory stream at this point; it's just that the ASP.NET engine refuses to present the contents from the memory stream.)
        context.Response.Body = originalBodyStream;
        await context.Response.Body.WriteAsync(memoryStream.ToArray());

        // Per @Necip Sunmaz's recommendation this also works:
        // Just make sure that the memoryStrream's pointer position is set back to 0 again.
        // await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
        // context.Response.Body = originalBodyStream;
    }
}
```

This way, you can present the web contents properly but also read the response body if you need to. This has been thoroughly been tested.

***Also, note that this code is written using .NET Core 3.1 and the C# language version 8.0.***
***@DalmTo confirmed that this code works with .NET 5 and C# 9.***

Comment: Works with .Net 5 + C# 9 as well. ❤

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day. Another point if you have a return File endpoint this code crushed. Remove Body.WriteAsync line and replace it with this code. await memoryStream.CopyToAsync(originalBodyStream);
httpContext.Response.Body = originalBodyStream;

Comment: @NecipSunmaz I've tested your code and it works  But I've also noticed that the app did not crash when the endpoint was serving the File (which is translated into FileStreamResult in the ASP.NET Core MVC) with the previous code. Will you tell me what type of "File" object you were returning from your endpoint?
Also, I've added your code to the example code above as an alternative way to copy back the content from the memory stream to the original response stream.

Comment: @D.K I wrote content type is dynamic. Code:  
new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider().TryGetContentType(name, out string contentType);  
return File(bytes, contentType);

Comment: @DaImTo i am using net core 5 but my result on page is null after reading the response body

Answer (score 9):

What you describe as a hack is actually the suggested approach of how to manage response streams in custom middleware.

Because of the pipeline nature of the middle ware design where each middle ware is unaware of the previous or next handler in the pipeline. There is no guarantee that the current middle ware would be the one writing the response unless it holds on to the response stream it was given before passing on a stream that it (the current middle ware) controls. This design was seen in OWIN and eventually baked into asp.net-core.

Once you start writing to the response stream it sends the body and headers (the response) to the client. If another handler down the pipeline does that before the current handler had a chance to then it wont be able to add anything to the response once it has been already sent.

Which again is not guaranteed to be the actual response stream if the previous middleware in the pipeline followed the same strategy of passing another stream down the line.

Referencing [ASP.NET Core Middleware Fundamentals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware)

> **Warning**
>
> Be careful modifying the `HttpResponse` after invoking `next`, because the
>   response may have already been sent to the client. You can use
>   [HttpResponse.HasStarted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.features.httpresponsefeature#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_Features_HttpResponseFeature_HasStarted) to check whether the headers have been sent.
>
> **Warning**
>
> Do not call `next.Invoke` after calling a `write` method. A middleware
>   component either produces a response or calls `next.Invoke`, but not
>   both.

Example of built in basic middlewares from **aspnet/BasicMiddleware** Github repo

[ResponseCompressionMiddleware.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/BasicMiddleware/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression/ResponseCompressionMiddleware.cs#L15)

```
/// <summary>
/// Invoke the middleware.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    if (!_provider.CheckRequestAcceptsCompression(context))
    {
        await _next(context);
        return;
    }

    var bodyStream = context.Response.Body;
    var originalBufferFeature = context.Features.Get<IHttpBufferingFeature>();
    var originalSendFileFeature = context.Features.Get<IHttpSendFileFeature>();

    var bodyWrapperStream = new BodyWrapperStream(context, bodyStream, _provider,
        originalBufferFeature, originalSendFileFeature);
    context.Response.Body = bodyWrapperStream;
    context.Features.Set<IHttpBufferingFeature>(bodyWrapperStream);
    if (originalSendFileFeature != null)
    {
        context.Features.Set<IHttpSendFileFeature>(bodyWrapperStream);
    }

    try
    {
        await _next(context);
        // This is not disposed via a using statement because we don't want to flush the compression buffer for unhandled exceptions,
        // that may cause secondary exceptions.
        bodyWrapperStream.Dispose();
    }
    finally
    {
        context.Response.Body = bodyStream;
        context.Features.Set(originalBufferFeature);
        if (originalSendFileFeature != null)
        {
            context.Features.Set(originalSendFileFeature);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET Core 3, the story is even worse: Even if you ignore the fact that we are talking about a web framework that has turned something as fundamental as reading web requests into a struggle with unintuitive workarounds and an API that changes between every version, then there's [an open issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14396) which means that if you use `EnableBuffering` "too late" (including late in your middleware pipeline), it won't do anything.

In my case, I used the hacky solution of adding the body to `HttpContext.Items` as early in the pipeline as possible. I'm sure this is awfully inefficient, and it ignores the sort of issues that arise when the body is large, but if you're looking for something off-the-shelf (as I was when I came across this question), then maybe this is helpful.

Concretely, I use the following middleware:

```
    public class RequestBodyStoringMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public RequestBodyStoringMiddleware(RequestDelegate next) =>
            _next = next;

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            httpContext.Request.EnableBuffering();
            string body;
            using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(
                httpContext.Request.Body, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, leaveOpen: true))
                body = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

            httpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;

            httpContext.Items["body"] = body;
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }
```

To use this, do a `app.UseMiddleware<RequestBodyStoringMiddleware>();` *as early as possible* in `Startup.Configure`; the issue is that depending on what else you're doing, the body stream might end up being consumed along the way, so the order matters. Then, when you need the body later (in the controller, or another piece of middleware), access it through `(string)HttpContext.Items["body"];`. Yes, your controllers now rely on implementation details of your configuration but what can you do.

Comment: Um, that issue was fixed in ASP.NET Core 3.1 in October 2019 already - i.e. before you posted this answer...

Comment: the question is about response body not request body.