# How to get the http body into a String in dot net core 2.0 using ReadAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, stream, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

I'm receiving and http post request, with raw body, and I'm trying to read the http body Stream into a String.

I'm using the basic Hello World web project generated by the *dotnet web* command. According to the [documentation](http://In%20the%20.NET%20Framework%204%20and%20earlier%20versions,%20you%20have%20to%20use%20methods%20such%20as%20BeginRead%20and%20EndRead%20to%20implement%20asynchronous%20I/O%20operations.%20These%20methods%20are%20still%20available%20in%20the%20.NET%20Framework%204.5%20to%20support%20legacy%20code;%20however,%20the%20new%20async%20methods,%20such%20as%20ReadAsync,%20WriteAsync,%20CopyToAsync,%20and%20FlushAsync,%20help%20you%20implement%20asynchronous%20I/O%20operations%20more%20easily.):

> In the .NET Framework 4 and earlier versions, you have to use methods
>   such as BeginRead and EndRead to implement asynchronous I/O
>   operations. These methods are still available in the .NET Framework
>   4.5 to support legacy code; however, the new async methods, such as ReadAsync, WriteAsync, CopyToAsync, and FlushAsync, help you implement
>   asynchronous I/O operations more easily.

So I tried with the [ReadAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813(v=vs.110).aspx) method with something like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // _controller = controller;
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {

        using (Stream Body = context.Request.Body) {
            byte[] result;
            result = new byte[context.Request.Body.Length];
            await context.Request.Body.ReadAsync(result, 0, (int)context.Request.Body.Length);

            String body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result).TrimEnd('\0');

            _log.LogInformation($"Body: {body}");
        }
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
    });
}
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1](http://In%20the%20.NET%20Framework%204%20and%20earlier%20versions,%20you%20have%20to%20use%20methods%20such%20as%20BeginRead%20and%20EndRead%20to%20implement%20asynchronous%20I/O%20operations.%20These%20methods%20are%20still%20available%20in%20the%20.NET%20Framework%204.5%20to%20support%20legacy%20code;%20however,%20the%20new%20async%20methods,%20such%20as%20ReadAsync,%20WriteAsync,%20CopyToAsync,%20and%20FlushAsync,%20help%20you%20implement%20asynchronous%20I/O%20operations%20more%20easily.)
>         Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/json/testing?id=2342&name=sas application/json
>   82 fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
>         Connection id "0HL7ISBH941G6", Request id "0HL7ISBH941G6:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the
>   application. System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not
>   supported.    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.FrameRequestStream.get_Length()
>   at mtss.ws.Startup.<b__4_0>d.MoveNext() in
>   /home/inspiron/devel/apps/dotnet/mtss-ws/Startup.cs:line 47

-- update

I could get something working setting the size of the buffer to Int16.MaxValue, but that way I can't read bodies larger that 32k.

Comment: Can you show us the entire code, how youre getting the data in the first place?

Comment: sure, there you go

Comment: Only async functions working!

This code had ran in my app.


<code>
using (Stream Body = request.Body)
{
    byte[] result;
    // int len = request.Body.Length    ---> Error
    result = new byte[UInt16.MaxValue];
    await request.Body.ReadAsync(result, 0, UInt16.MaxValue);

    return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result).TrimEnd('\0');
}
</code>

Answer (score 11):

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403941/how-to-read-asp-net-core-response-body) at SO that helped my find the following solution:

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
{

    string body = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEnd();
    _log.LogInformation($"Body: {body}");
    _log.LogInformation($"Body.Length: {body.Length}");

    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
});
```

and the async version is pretty much alike:

```
    string body = await new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do it...

Answer (score 5):

I, too, had issues with ReadAsync stopping short of the full content. My solution is similar to the one offered by [opensas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47633/opensas), however, I did it with a "using" so the StreamReader's dispose method would be called automatically. I also added the UTF8 encoding option to the StreamReader.

```
using StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8);
string body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync ();
```