# Reading the Response.Body stream in Filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I writing my filter that running after a sever method call and print its content to Console. The code is written in ASP.NET core v2.1:

```
public class MyCustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {

        // ERROR on the next line!
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Response.Body))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }

        base.OnResultExecuted(context);
    }
}
```

The result - exception:

> Stream was not readable.

Further investigation leads me to the point that the stream (`context.HttpContext.Response`) has those values:

1. CanRead = false
2. CanSeek = false

That can explain why it cant read the body...

How to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you need to do this . `context.Result` is an instance of `IActionResult` , you can manipulate it as you like . If you do want to read the `Response.Body` , there's something hacky can be done.

Since the default `Response.Body` is not a readable `Stream` , in order to make the body readable , **we need to hijack the response , namely replace the `Body` with our own instance of `Stream`** :

1. We can create a brand new memory stream dynamically before action is executing , and hijack the default `Response.Body` stream .
2. When action executed , read the stream using a `StreamReader`, do some work,  and set the `Response.Body=your new stream` .

It's safe to hijack the `Response.Body` with a plain memory stream because the type of `Body` is plain `Stream`.

```
public class MyCustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private MemoryStream responseBody ;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context){
        this.responseBody=new MemoryStream();
        // hijack the real stream with our own memory stream 
        context.HttpContext.Response.Body = responseBody;
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {

        responseBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        // read our own memory stream 
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseBody))
        {
            var actionResult= sr.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(actionResult);
            // create new stream and assign it to body 
            // context.HttpContext.Response.Body = ;
        }

        // no ERROR on the next line!

        base.OnResultExecuted(context);
    }
}
```

For a testing purpose , I create an action method :

```
[MyCustomFilter]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return Ok("it wooooooooorks");
}
```

[image]

Comment: No need to fiddle around with your own implementations. Just call `Request.EnableRewind();` (ASP.NET Core 2.0 and later) and the `Request.Stream` will be replaced with a rewindable version. As with your solution, people should always be aware of the memory/performance implications of doing so: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.internal.bufferinghelper.enablerewind?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: @Tseng  I didn't realize that . Thanks very much , your solution is much better  than mine.

Comment: @Tseng Hi,  sorry for disturbing you. But I cannot figure out how to enable rewind for `Response` like `Request.EnableRewind()`. Could you please do me a favor ?  Thanks .

Comment: Just by calling `Request.EnableRewind()`, but you have to do it **before** anything has been read from the Request. If some other middleware has started to read from it, its too late to call `EnableRewind()`. `EnableRewind()` is an extension method (as seen in the linked documentation) and you need to declare the namespace import for it to work: `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal;`. But use it with a bit of care, its a so-called "pubinternal" (internal API that has public accessor), means may be subject for (breaking) changes in future

Comment: @Tseng Thanks for you very detailed explanation.  I just tried with an ` app.Use(async (context , next)=>{context.Request.EnableRewind();await next();});` before any other middlewares, however the `context.Response.Body` is still not readable. Does I miss something ? And I find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43404745/10091607) . Will the  `Request.EnableRewind()` apply for `context.Response.Body`?

Comment: EnableRewind, or EnableBuffering how it is now released as, is only useable for a Request, not for a Response.

Comment: @itminus this almost solves my problem! Please can you very kindly show how to create new stream and assign it to body?

Comment: Can someone please show me how to restore the original body? I tried the code above but the response is now empty on browser side. Thank you!

Comment: I have been struggling to get this to work. The response gets hijacked/intercepted with success, and I can modify the response put it in a new stream but assigning the new stream to the response body gives me an empty response in Postman.
I would really have loved to see how the assigning the response body to the new stream would look like, and seeing the the result in postman.

Answer (score 4):

Use Actionfilter instead of middleware:

```
var resultnext = await next();
var objectResult = resultnext.Result as ObjectResult;
var resultValue = objectResult.Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what do you want to achieve.
If you want to get the response values or just to see the result you can use

```
context.Result or context.Result.Value
```

If you want to modify the response or just to log the entire response you should use a middleware.

here is a good example https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-middleware-to-log-requests-and-responses-in-asp-net-core/

hope it helps