# How to get HttpRequest body in .net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, streamreader, httpcontext

I want to get Http Request body in .net core , I used this code:

```
using (var reader
    = new StreamReader(req.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    bodyStr = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
req.Body.Position = 0
```

But I got this error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'FileBufferingReadStream'.

An error occurs after the using statement of the line

How to get HttpRequest Body in .net core?
and how to fix this error?

Comment: See Tseng's comment below my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52849296/reading-the-response-body-stream-in-filter/52850301#52850301) .  [Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.internal.bufferinghelper.enablerewind?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading the Response.Body stream in Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52849296/reading-the-response-body-stream-in-filter)

Comment: Give us some more context, where are you using this code for example ? Show some more surrounding code.

Comment: the code snippet won't throw the exception. If you can provide more details of your code it would help us to understand your problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use this extension method to get httpRequest Body:

```
   public static string GetRawBodyString(this HttpContext httpContext, Encoding encoding)
    {
        var body = "";
        if (httpContext.Request.ContentLength == null || !(httpContext.Request.ContentLength > 0) ||
            !httpContext.Request.Body.CanSeek) return body;
        httpContext.Request.EnableRewind();
        httpContext.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpContext.Request.Body, encoding, true, 1024, true))
        {
            body = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        httpContext.Request.Body.Position = 0;
        return body;
    }
```

> The important thing is that HttpRequest.Body is a Stream type And when the StreamReader is disposed, HttpRequest.Body is also disposed.

I had this problem until I found the below link in GitHub:
Refer to the below link and the GetBody method
https://github.com/devdigital/IdentityServer4TestServer/blob/3eaf72f9e1f7086b5cfacb5ecc8b1854ad3c496c/Source/IdentityServer4TestServer/Token/TokenCreationMiddleware.cs

Comment: nice,I had this problem before I found that link

Answer (score 2):

Simple workaround:

```
using (var content = new StreamContent(Request.Body))
{
     var contentString = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please review [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62513305/6210068) by [Stephen Wilkinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9306170/stephen-wilkinson)

Use the following for **.NET Core 3.1**

**Startup.cs**

```
app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    context.Request.EnableBuffering(); // calls EnableRewind() `https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/4ef204e13b88c0734e0e94a1cc4c0ef05f40849e/src/Http/Http/src/Extensions/HttpRequestRewindExtensions.cs#L23`
    return next();
});
```

You should then be able to rewind as per other answers:

```
httpContext.Request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me, but I was reading the body twice.

```
    public static string ReadRequestBody(this HttpRequest request, Encoding encoding)
    {
        var body = "";
        request.EnableRewind();

        if (request.ContentLength == null ||
            !(request.ContentLength > 0) ||
            !request.Body.CanSeek)
        {
            return body;
        }

        request.Body.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body, encoding, true, 1024, true))
        {
            body = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        //Reset the stream so data is not lost
        request.Body.Position = 0;

        return body;
    }
```