# Overwriting content in HttpContext.Response.Body in OnResultExecuted using ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api2

I have been trying to overwrite my response body with something else. In my example I am trying to replace some words with another word, just for the sake of this example.

I have no problem with 'Hijacking' the response body and changing the content. However when I assign the new response body to 'HttpContext.Response.Body' my response is empty in Postman. There is no response at all.

```
public class MyActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyMessageFilter> _logger;
    private MemoryStream _responseBody;

    public MyActionFilter(ILogger<MyMessageFilter> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
       _logger.LogInformation("OnActionExecuting");
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        this._responseBody = new MemoryStream();
        context.HttpContext.Response.Body = _responseBody;
        _logger.LogInformation("OnActionExecuted");
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("OnResultExecuting");
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
         _responseBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        //read the memory stream 
        using var sr = new StreamReader(_responseBody);
        
        // Old stream
        var oldResponseBody = sr.ReadToEnd();

        var memStream = new MemoryStream();
        context.HttpContext.Response.Body = memStream;
        memStream.Position = 0;
        
        // Replace old with
        var responseBody = oldResponseBody.Replace("Anything", "Something", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        var stream = GenerateStreamFromString(responseBody);

        context.HttpContext.Response.Body = stream;
        base.OnResultExecuted(context);
    }

    public static Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(s);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
    }
}
```

In my controller class I decorate my controller method with MyMessageFilter

```
 [HttpPost]
 [TypeFilter(typeof(MyMessageFilter))]
 [ActionName("WeatherForecastWeek")]
 public WeatherForecastResponse GetWeekForecast()
 {
   ...
 }
```

I have found some examples, but with all of them I can come as far as retrieving my response body and manipulating the content. However when creating a new stream and assigning the 'HttpContext.Response.Body' my response is empty.

Can anyone help me with clarifying, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Well, thanks for your response, have you tried to parse your response into a class then deserilize it and finally bind into your response stream? Is that works for you?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron as I was saying your example is making use of a middleware spun up in program.cs. I am looking for the ActionFilter solution. 
I am tryng to implement this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52849296/reading-the-response-body-stream-in-filter/52850301#comment135837706_52850301
But as you can see in my comment, I am struggling to make it work with modifying the response.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your response, I will take a look the link you have shared.