# Logging all data returned by .net core REST api

Tags: asp.net-core

I'ld like to be able to log everything that is returned by my asp.net core REST api. I tried achieving this by adding a global ActionFilter that would intercept everyt result generated in OnResultExecuted method.

```
    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
    {
        base.OnResultExecuted(context);
    }
```

Problem is I can't get the data contained in `context.Result`. I call the following method `context.Result.ExecuteResultAsync(context);` which throwme an error :

> 'StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.'

Comment: While it's tempting to want to do this on a global basis, that's not a great idea, particularly if your API deals with any sensitive information. It would be better to explicitly log what you want in the actions, and sanitize any PII or other sensitive info manually.

Comment: Check out [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403941/how-to-read-asp-net-core-response-body), you might find the solution there.

Answer (score 0):

For accessing `Result`, you need to use it after `base.OnResultExecuted(context);`

A simple demo:

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
{
    base.OnResultExecuted(context);

    var result = (ObjectResult)context.Result;
}
```