# Difference Between context.Response.Body.Write() ;& context.Response.Body = new memorystream();

Tags: c#

1st approach

```
finally{
// here when i return response am getting proper output
context.Response.Body.Write();    
}
```

2nd approach

```
finally{
// here when i return response am notgetting the required body in client
context.Response.Body = new memorystream();    
}
```

Comment: At first approach you are return response directly. At second approach you are getting response by a memorystream from RAM, stack, queue etc.

Comment: Look This Link :-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43403941/how-to-read-asp-net-core-response-body

Comment: i dont wanna read my response multiple times , i wanna use use either of the approach . But when i use memory stream am not getting the body and when i use  write method am getting the proper body content