# Set response header in middleware when using ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an asp .net core web api where I need to set some headers in the response. This based on the body of the response. (calculate md5)

I would like to do this in a custom middleware so that every request will have the same response headers.

I tried the following setup:

First I have a controller with a simple endpoint:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Test")]
    public IActionResult DoTest()
    {
        var result = new { someProp = "somePropValue" };
        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

I added a custom middleware class:

```
public class CustomResponseHandler
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public CustomResponseHandler(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        await _next(context);
        context.Response.Headers.Add("foo", "fii");
    }
}
```

In startup I added this middleware using the Configure method:

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseMiddleware<CustomResponseHandler>();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

When I run this, the context.Response.Headers.Add("foo", "fii"); line does get executed.

It also executes after returning the result from the endpoint which is perfect.

However, when I look at the response, the header "foo" is still missing.

Is there a way to achieve this.

I noticed I do get the header when I add it before returning the result in the endpoint:

```
    public IActionResult DoTest()
    {
        var result = new { someProp = "somePropValue" };
        Response.Headers.Add("foo", "fii");
        return Ok(result);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the time `next()` has executed in your middleware, the server has already started sending the response to the client. This means that headers can not be modified anymore. Quote from this [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#create-a-middleware-pipeline-with-iapplicationbuilder):

> Don't call next.Invoke after the response has been sent to the client. Changes to HttpResponse after the response has started throw an exception. For example, setting headers and a status code throw an exception. Writing to the response body after calling next:
>
> - May cause a protocol violation. For example, writing more than the stated Content-Length.
> - May corrupt the body format. For example, writing an HTML footer to a CSS file.

What you should do is to either add the headers before calling `next()`, or add it in a hook in `Response.OnStarting`:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("foo", "fii");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });
    await next();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this and this does add the header. However, I was not able to access the response body in this callback. (I suppose it is not yet filled in). So I don't know if it is possible to calculate an md5 hash or content length in this callback?

Comment: In that case, you may want to [replace the response stream with your own seekable and readable stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43404745/9847515). This will give you more control over the stream, e.g. rewind and re-read from it, get its length, etc. In that case you don't need the `OnStarting` callback. Note that this may have performance or memory implications though.

Comment: Ok thank you for the insight! Seeing the implications I realise this is probably not the best way to go forward and will implement it in a different way.

Comment: scharnyw you are so helpful!