# .Net 6 - Custom Middleware Logging - Mixing responses and requests

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-middleware

I have written custom middleware that logs requests and responses made to our APIs.

What I've realised is that the requests and responses are not matching, they seem to get mixed up, which is very odd.

This seems to happen when a lot of requests are made within a very short time. Not sure how, but it seems like when `LogResponse` is called, it's not within the same scope as `LogRequest`.

I've implemented a version of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43404745/2286743

Am I missing anything?

*`Trimmed down version of actual code`*

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;

namespace Middleware
{
    public class Web
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        private Logging.AuditLog _auditLog;

        public Web(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                EndpointMetadataCollection endpointMetaData = context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint.Metadata;

                context.Request.EnableBuffering();

                await LogRequest(context);
                await LogResponse(context);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Custom exception logging here
            }
        }

        public async Task LogRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            IHttpRequestFeature features = context.Features.Get<IHttpRequestFeature>();
            string url = $"{features.Scheme}://{context.Request.Host.Value}{features.RawTarget}";

            IFormCollection form = null;
            string formString = string.Empty;

            if (context.Request.HasFormContentType)
            {
                form = context.Request.Form;
            }
            else
            {
                formString = await new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                var injectedRequestStream = new MemoryStream();
                byte[] bytesToWrite = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formString);
                injectedRequestStream.Write(bytesToWrite, 0, bytesToWrite.Length);
                injectedRequestStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                context.Request.Body = injectedRequestStream;
            }

            _auditLog = new Logging.AuditLog()
            {
                RemoteHost = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(),
                HttpURL = url,
                LocalAddress = context.Connection.LocalIpAddress.ToString(),
                Headers = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Request.Headers),
                Form = form != null ? Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(form) : formString
            };
        }

        public async Task LogResponse(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (_auditLog == null)
            {
                await _next(context);
                return;
            }

            Stream originalBody = context.Response.Body;

            try
            {

                using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    context.Response.Body = memStream;

                    await _next(context);

                    memStream.Position = 0;
                    string responseBody = new StreamReader(memStream).ReadToEnd();

                    _auditLog.ResponseStatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode;
                    _auditLog.ResponseBody = responseBody;
                    _auditLog = _auditLog.Save();

                    memStream.Position = 0;
                    await memStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                _auditLog?.Save();
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Response.Body = originalBody;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any `await next()` in the `Invoke` method

Comment: Ah it's in the `LogResponse`. Not the most obvious place but anyway... But you're calling it twice. Please move `await next(context)` to the `Invoke` method, inbetween `LogRequest` and `LogResponse`, and call it only once!!!

Comment: @Pieterjan, you've got it wrong. The first `await _next(context);` is called when the `_auditLog ` object is null. The second is when the logging process continues and it needs to log the response. It is also not erroneous.

Comment: Please go th https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73371732/serilog-configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I was able to resolve this after some investigations.

The global variables set, is what was causing the mix-up. They are being re-used by all other endpoints.

`private Logging.AuditLog _auditLog;` has to be used within the methods to function as intended. If set globally, when a new endpoint is invoked, it will re-write the `_auditLog` variable with a new object. The other endpoint, still being executed, will have it's object for `_auditLog` replaced. That caused duplicates and mismatching `response` to `request` bodies.

The changes I made:

#### OLD

```
await LogRequest(context);
await LogResponse(context);
```

#### NEW

```
var auditLog = await LogRequest(context);
await LogResponse(context, auditLog);
```

The rest is self explanatory.

Here is the full page:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features;

namespace Middleware
{
    public class Web
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public Web(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                EndpointMetadataCollection endpointMetaData = context.Features.Get<IEndpointFeature>()?.Endpoint.Metadata;

                context.Request.EnableBuffering();

                var auditLog = await LogRequest(context);
                await LogResponse(context, auditLog);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                throw;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Custom exception logging here
            }
        }

        public async Task<Logging.AuditLog> LogRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            IHttpRequestFeature features = context.Features.Get<IHttpRequestFeature>();
            string url = $"{features.Scheme}://{context.Request.Host.Value}{features.RawTarget}";

            IFormCollection form = null;
            string formString = string.Empty;

            if (context.Request.HasFormContentType)
            {
                form = context.Request.Form;
            }
            else
            {
                formString = await new StreamReader(context.Request.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
                var injectedRequestStream = new MemoryStream();
                byte[] bytesToWrite = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formString);
                injectedRequestStream.Write(bytesToWrite, 0, bytesToWrite.Length);
                injectedRequestStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                context.Request.Body = injectedRequestStream;
            }

            return new Logging.AuditLog()
            {
                RemoteHost = context.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString(),
                HttpURL = url,
                LocalAddress = context.Connection.LocalIpAddress.ToString(),
                Headers = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context.Request.Headers),
                Form = form != null ? Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(form) : formString
            };
        }

        public async Task LogResponse(HttpContext context, Logging.AuditLog auditLog)
        {
            if (auditLog == null)
            {
                await _next(context);
                return;
            }

            Stream originalBody = context.Response.Body;

            try
            {

                using (var memStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    context.Response.Body = memStream;

                    await _next(context);

                    memStream.Position = 0;
                    string responseBody = new StreamReader(memStream).ReadToEnd();

                    auditLog.ResponseStatusCode = context.Response.StatusCode;
                    auditLog.ResponseBody = responseBody;
                    auditLog = auditLog.Save();

                    memStream.Position = 0;
                    await memStream.CopyToAsync(originalBody);
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                auditLog?.Save();
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                context.Response.Body = originalBody;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where I can find Logging.AuditLog ?

Comment: @KonsultanITBandung, the `Logging.AuditLog` class in the above answer is a custom class. You will have to create your own if you'd like to implement the above.

Comment: Thank you @Marius it works, if possible, how can I see response body result ? [Debugger watcer](https://prnt.sc/BhFHm4CDf_Db) , because I need response body looks like this  [JsonResult](https://prnt.sc/hCG3KbPI8aJn)

Comment: I'm sorry @Marius, I think my ResponseBody was compressed because I'm using gzip compression for the response. ```app.UseResponseCompression();``` . (solved)