# ASP.NET core REST service returns invalid json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, corrupt

We have an ASP.NET core REST service (.NET5). It works fine. But if we call a GET method from two browsers simultaneously, the returned JSON becomes invalid.

The JSON looks scrambled:

```
{
   "assemblyId":null,                             ┌─ something invalid was inserted here
   "stepScrapQuantity":0,                         ▼
   "webViewer3dFileUrl":"http://172.20.33.188:8000me":"00:00:00",
   "currentProcessTime":"00:00:00"                
}                   ▲                             
                    └─ it looks like this string was inserted above
```

- The returned DTO is automatically serialized by the built-in JSON-serializer (System.Text.Json) from ASP.NET.
- On each GET, the JSON is messed up differently (random). Sometimes **keys** are messed up, sometimes **values** are messed up, sometimes it's all fine.
- It looks like there's a multithreading issue in System.Text.Json
- Our backend runs in a docker container.
- It's not reproducible in debug-mode (localhost).
- It's only reproducible with large JSON-Data (in our case 1.5 MB)
- It only fails on a real notwork interface (on localhost it's all fine). So maybe it's a network issue.

Did anyone notice a similar issue?

**EDIT (2022/10/14)**
The longer we investigate the problem, the stranger it becomes.
The logging of the JSON message in our backend-middleware shows a **valid** JSON. The received JSON on frontend side is invalid. That means the bug is not in our backend. The payload is broken somewhere between backend and frontend. That's only reproducible when the backend runs as docker container and the service is called remotely (not from localhost).

Looking at this layer model, I wonder if it's possible that docker engine can break the JSON:

[image]

source: https://docs.mirantis.com/containers/v3.0/dockeree-ref-arch/networking/scalable-container-networks.html

Comment: Do you produce the json or you are just serializing an object?

Comment: Needs more info, at the least where the json is coming from.

Comment: What type are you returning?  Does it have a custom [`JsonConverter<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1)?  Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: Oh this is interesting: looks like `Utf8JsonReader` doesn't properly enforce that well-formed JSON is being written.  If, in a `JsonConverter<T>`, the `WriteJson()` method writes two property names in a row, the writer will happily emit such malformed JSON.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lv7gSS which roughly reproduces the JSON you see.  Is there any chance that is what is happening here?

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. I have edited my post to hopefully answer your questions.

Thank you for the example on "fiddle". I don't think the problem can be incorrectly filled data because sometimes the **keys** from the JSON are messed up.

Comment: A lot of people use System.Text.Json, it's low probable to have an issue inside it. Trouble in your controller method maybe. Can you show how your controller action looks like?

Comment: Do you have any response filters or custom middleware's?

Comment: @Dimitry: I agree that System.Text.Json is too widely used to have such a basic bug. I can exclude the controller as bug, because the object is serialized outside the controller.

Comment: @SilernTremor: Good input. Our custom middleware could really be the cause, but even after disabling it, the bug still occurs. We don't use "response filters".

Comment: Than let's just call it filters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-6.0, are there any?

Comment: How is the DTO instantiated? is it from a stream? Is it from an async IEnumerable? Is it singleton / static DTO producer?

Comment: Still, by the way it looks, it indicates either a middleware or filter overlapping responses.

Comment: @SilentTremor: We use some filters, but no custom made. Disabling them does not fix it. The DTO's are produced by AutoMapper. I tend to think that the problem is caused on a layer that we have no control over (network components, Docker, ...). I'll go on. As soon as I have found the reason I'll post it here.

Comment: @Templar_VII as I said, problem is in the middleware, and you answered my question without knowing it, stating that code "logging of the JSON message in our backend-middleware shows a valid JSON" is actually causing the issue, I bet there is an instance of bad codding. Why don't post that middleware code? Hint, stream from context.Response.Body is used incorrectly, I bet it with you. And, stop wasting client money, listen and understand what Stack Overflow members tells you.

Comment: @SilentTremor: That's the custom middleware we use: https://gist.github.com/furkandeveloper/d6b2f5608d02eb212d7ec9e53db63893/revisions But even after disabling this middlware, the bug persists.

Comment: Problem here: using (var responseBody = new MemoryStream()) reason being requests larger than 85,000 bytes can result into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap what can cause memory leaks, so instead of memory stream use RecyclableMemoryStream, like so:
var myManager =  new RecyclableMemoryStreamManager(); using (var responseBody = myManager .GetStream()

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/Microsoft.IO.RecyclableMemoryStream is the nuget package for RecyclableMemoryStream

Comment: And another recommendation, when parsing response stream to string (or maybe even for large requests), read stream in chunks.

Comment: A good example on stack overflow can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52328142/3898495 and there are other answers, just be carful on what dotnet version is running, on dotnet 6 or 7 things are not the same.

Comment: @Templar_VII if disabling it problem persists, than there's definitely a similar problem in your code, is is not another middleware, than it might be another case of memory leaks inside your code (controller, service), someone once told me, if you cannot find an explanation to the problem it means problem is in your code.

Comment: @SilentTremor: Thanks a lot for all your help. But you have lost the bet. The bug was not in our code. It's a networking issue on the server. At least the problem was solved by disabling TSO.

Comment: @Templar_VII happy for you, I really am, not 100% sure know what TSO does, but reading the documentation I assume is transferring large packages in smaller chunks, operations that puts response body in stand by, and here memory leaks happens, inside API, inside code.

Comment: So, in my opinion problem is not fixed, even worse, it will increase your processor usage, increase the costs because of scaling. And I think in case of a low latency connection problem will resurface.

Comment: Final comment, and then I let it be, TCP protocol implies open connection between sender and receiver, meaning what is flowing trough cannot interfere with another TCP  packages of another TCP connection. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error seems to be beyond our control.

We recorded the traffic with Wireshark. That sowed us that all malformed strings in the JSON are starting points of a TCP package. So it seems the TCP packages are reassembled incorrectly.

I don't know which component is responsible for splitting and assembling the TCP packages, but it is certainly outside our software.

[image]

What supports this theory are lots of packages that are "out-of-order":
[image]

**Solution:**
Disabling TCP Segmentation Offload (TSO) finally solved the problem.
https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/7.0/com.vmware.vsphere.networking.doc/GUID-D80AEC2F-E0DA-4172-BFFD-B721BF36C2E8.html

Answer (score 1):

Your REST service code is not thread-safe. You have global variables that are used by every GET call, so data gets mixed up.

Comment: Yes that's exactly how it feels. It reacts like there's a static varible in the serialization code. But in a ASP.NET core REST API, all the serialization is hidden in Microsoft Libraries. There's no code from our side.

Comment: @Templar_VII please show us your code, perhaps we find the problem/solution

Comment: I'm working on a sample application to reproduce the bug. I can't share my entire project. It's huge and it has to many dependencies. I'll let you know when I have the code ready.

Comment: @Templar_VII Just select the relevant part of the code. Yes, that may be hard. In your case, usually the method that serves the GET request is just one small method.