# ASP.NET Core 6 MVC: how can I get json data returned from controller in middleware?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, middleware

I wrote a very simple middleware. It works when a request is made to the post method on a certain path. but I need to read the json data returned from that post method in the middleware. How can I do?

Code of my middleware:

```
public class QuartzStopStartMiddleware
{
        RequestDelegate _next;

        public QuartzStopStartMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            await _next.Invoke(context);
            
            // In this if block, I need to find out whether the json result returned from the controller is true
            if (context.Request.Path == "/Home/JobPage" && context.Request.Method == "POST")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("post jobpage");
            }
        }
}
```

Inside the if block, I check if the method is post and the path is 'JobPage'. but I need to add a third check. If the json result returned from the 'JobPage' controller is true, it must be inside this if.

JobPage controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult JobPage(JobTableDTO jobTableDTO)
{
    try
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return Json(jobTableDTO);

        jobTableDTO.CustomUserId = userManager.GetUserId(User);
        jobTableDTO.JOB_KEY = "Job1";
        jobTableDTO.IS_ACTIVE = true;
        jobTableDTO.DESCRIPTION = "JOB1";

        DOMAIN.Models.JobTable jobTable = _mapper.Map<DOMAIN.Models.JobTable>(jobTableDTO);

        if (_jobServices.JobTableKaydet(jobTable) == 1)
        {
            // Console.WriteLine(SchedulerHelper.ResetJob());
            return Json(new { result = true });
        }
        else
            return Json(new { result = false });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        return Json(new { result = false });
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am returning json result in controller, true or false. If this controller returns true, it should go to 'if' in the middleware, i.e. as a third condition of 'if' in middleware result == true.

Example:

```
if (context.Request.Path == "/Home/JobPage" 
    && context.Request.Method == "POST"
    && context.JobPage.Result == true)
```

as I showed in the example. I need to check whether the result in the json data returned from the controller is true

Comment: Look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43404745/4163446
After you read Response.Body you propably should deserialize json to C# object. You can create class  with `result` property or use dynamic.

Comment: ```app.UseMiddleware<QuartzStopStartMiddleware>();```

Answer (score 0):

I think a [Result Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-7.0#result-filters) is a more appropriate solution.

```
public class MyResponseFilter : IAsyncResultFilter
{
    public async Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext context,
                                             ResultExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var Value = (context.Result as JsonResult).Value.ToString();
        var Method = context.HttpContext.Request.Method;
        var Path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path.ToString();
            
        if (Value.Contains("True") && Method == "POST" && Path == "/Home/JobPage")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("post jobpage");
            await next();
        }
        else
        {
            context.Cancel = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Register in Program:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<MyResponseFilter>();
```

Apply a filter to the corresponding action:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(MyResponseFilter))]
public JsonResult JobPage(JobTableDTO jobTableDTO) {}
```