# Differ IOutputFormatter per endpoint in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a legacy ASP.NET Web API 2 app which must be ported to ASP.NET Core 6 and it has the following behaviour:

1. Some controllers return responses in Pascal-case Json
2. Some controllers return responses in camel-case Json
3. All controllers have the same authentication/authorization, but they return different objects using different serializers for 401/403 cases.

In ASP.NET Web API 2 it was easily solved with `IControllerConfiguration` (to set the formatter for a controller), `AuthorizeAttribute` (to throw exceptions for 401/403), `ExceptionFilterAttribute` to set 401/403 status code and response which will be serialized using correct formatter.

In ASP.NET Core, it seems that `IOutputFormatter` collection is global for all controllers and it is not available during `UseAuthentication` + `UseAuthorization` pipeline where it terminates in case of failure.

Best I could come up with is to always "succeed" in authentication / authorization with some failing flag in claims and add `IActionFilter` as first filter checking those flags, but it looks very hacky.

Is there some better approach?

**Update1:**

Implementing different output formatters for IActionResult from controller or IFilter (including IExceptionFilter) is not very difficult.
What I want is to be able to either set IActionResult or use IOutputFormatter related to Action identified by UseRouting for Authentication/Authorization error or IAuthorizationHandler, but looks like all those auth steps are invoked before either ActionContext or IOutputFormatter is invoked.
So 2 approaches I see now:

1. hack auth code to "always pass" and handle HttpContext.Items["MyRealAuthResult"] object in IActionFilter
2. expose V1OutputFormatter/V2OutputFormatter in a static field and duplicate selection logic in HandleChallengeAsync/HandleForbiddenAsync based on to what controller/action it was routed from UseRouting step.

Here is sample app that uses auth and has 2 endpoints:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>, MvcOptionsSetup>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.AddScheme<DefAuthHandler>("defscheme", "defscheme");
});
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options => 
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder("defscheme")
        .RequireAssertion(context =>
            // false here should result in Pascal case POCO for WeatherForecastV1Controller
            // and camel case POCO for WeatherForecastV2Controller
            context.User.Identities.Any(c => c.AuthenticationType == "secretheader"))
        .Build())
    .AddSingleton<IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler, AuthorizationResultHandler>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

public class AuthorizationResultHandler : IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
{
    private readonly AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler _handler;
    public AuthorizationResultHandler()
    {
        _handler = new AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler();
    }

    public async Task HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
    {
        // Can't set ActionContext.Response here or use IOutputFormatter
        await _handler.HandleAsync(next, context, policy, authorizeResult);
    }
}

public class DefAuthHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
{
    public DefAuthHandler(IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options, ILoggerFactory logger, UrlEncoder encoder, ISystemClock clock)
        : base(options, logger, encoder, clock) { }

    protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
    {
        var claims = new List<ClaimsIdentity>();
        if (Request.Headers.ContainsKey("secretheader")) claims.Add(new ClaimsIdentity("secretheader"));
        return AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(new ClaimsPrincipal(claims), "defscheme"));
    }
}

public class MvcOptionsSetup : IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>
{
    private readonly ArrayPool<char> arrayPool;
    private readonly MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions mvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions;
    public MvcOptionsSetup(ArrayPool<char> arrayPool, IOptions<MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions> mvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions)
    {
        this.arrayPool = arrayPool;
        this.mvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions = mvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions.Value;
    }

    public void Configure(MvcOptions options)
    {
        options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new V1OutputFormatter(arrayPool, options, mvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions));
        options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new V2OutputFormatter(arrayPool, options, mvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions));
    }
}

public class V1OutputFormatter : NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter
{
    public V1OutputFormatter(ArrayPool<char> charPool, MvcOptions mvcOptions, MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions? jsonOptions)
        : base(new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver() }, charPool, mvcOptions, jsonOptions) { }

    public override bool CanWriteResult(OutputFormatterCanWriteContext context)
    {
        var controllerDescriptor = context.HttpContext.GetEndpoint()?.Metadata.GetMetadata<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptor>();
        return controllerDescriptor?.ControllerName == "WeatherForecastV1";
    }
}

public class V2OutputFormatter : NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter
{
    public V2OutputFormatter(ArrayPool<char> charPool, MvcOptions mvcOptions, MvcNewtonsoftJsonOptions? jsonOptions)
        : base(new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() }, charPool, mvcOptions, jsonOptions) { }

    public override bool CanWriteResult(OutputFormatterCanWriteContext context)
    {
        var controllerDescriptor = context.HttpContext.GetEndpoint()?.Metadata.GetMetadata<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptor>();
        return controllerDescriptor?.ControllerName == "WeatherForecastV2";
    }
}

[ApiController]
[Authorize]
[Route("v1/weatherforecast")]
public class WeatherForecastV1Controller : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        // This must be Pascal case
        return Ok(new WeatherForecast() { Summary = "summary" });
    }
}

[ApiController]
[Authorize]
[Route("v2/weatherforecast")]
public class WeatherForecastV2Controller : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        // This must be camel case
        return Ok(new WeatherForecast() { Summary = "summary" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no way to configure controllers independently, then you could use some middleware to convert output from selected controllers that meet a path-based predicate.

```
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.Containes("v2/"), cfg =>
{
   app.UseMiddleware<JsonCapitalizer>(); 
});
app.Run();
```

And then create a JsonCapitalizer class to convert output from any path that contains "v2/".  Note, this middleware will not run if the predicate in MapWhen is not satisfied.

```
public class JsonCapitalizer
{
    readonly RequestDelegate _nextRequestDelegate;

    public RequestLoggingMiddleware(
        RequestDelegate nextRequestDelegate)
    {
        _nextRequestDelegate = nextRequestDelegate;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        await _nextRequestDelegate(httpContext);

        // Get the httpContext.Response
        // Capitalize it
        // Rewrite the response
    }
}
```

There may be better ways, but that's the first that comes to mind.

The following link will help with manipulation of the response body:

[How to read ASP.NET Core Response.Body?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43403941/)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced such a problem in ASP Core 7 and ended up with writing an `attribute`.

So the `attribute` will be applied on each `Action` where the `response type` has to be converted. You can write many an `attribute` for `camelcase` response and another attribute for `pascalcase`. The `attribute` will look like below for `CamelCase`

```
public class CamelCaseAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static readonly SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter formatter = new SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter(new()
    {
        ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles,
        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
    });

    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Result is ObjectResult objectResult)
        {
            objectResult.Formatters
                .RemoveType<NewtonsoftJsonOutputFormatter>();
            objectResult.Formatters.Add(formatter);
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(context);
        }
    }
}
```

And on the `Contoller` `Action` you can use it like below

```
 [CamelCase]
    public async IAsyncEnumerable<ResponseResult<IReadOnlyList<VendorBalanceReportDto>>> VendorBalanceReport([FromQuery] Paginator paginator, [FromQuery] VendorBalanceReportFilter filter, [EnumeratorCancellation] CancellationToken token)
    {
        var response = _reportService.VendorBalanceReport(paginator, filter, token);

        await foreach (var emailMessage in response)
        {
            yield return emailMessage;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should reuse the JsonSerializerOptions object, not doing so results in bad performance at scale.

Comment: @davidfowl, doesnt the above code add the json serilaizer object there like this `objectResult.Formatters.Add(formatter);`.

Comment: You're adding to the formatter list per ObjectResult instance. This is allocating a new formatting per request. Very inefficient.

Comment: Added my thoughts about this in Update1 in main topic. My main problem is how to use same something inherited from TextOutputFormatter for IActionResult and Authentication/Authorization errors from either UseAuthentication/UseAuthorization or IAuthorizationFilter.

Comment: @davidfowl, thanks you very much cor sharing such knowledge. Is there better way that u suggest could work?