# How to read response body inside IHttpLoggingInterceptor.OnResponseAsync?

Tags: c#, logging, stream, .net-8.0

It's used for customizing logging of built-in [http logger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-logging/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#ihttplogginginterceptor).

When I tried to read `HttpLoggingInterceptorContext.HttpContext.Response.Body` via `StreamReader` it simply returns empty string.

When I tried to move that code inside `HttpLoggingInterceptorContext.HttpContext.Response.OnStarting` it's still an empty string.

Inside `HttpLoggingInterceptorContext.HttpContext.Response.OnCompleted` HttpContext is already unavailable from `HttpLoggingInterceptorContext.HttpContext`

I was trying to use [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43404745/7402089) for the body reading itself. Was experimenting with multiple small changes while trying to adopt that middleware code to this interceptor code but it still doesn't work. How do I do that?

Previously I was trying to simply implement custom middleware for logging purposes. And I was also stuck at the point where I was trying to read a response body. However in my custom code I was getting `System.InvalidOperationException: The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started.` at that line where it was trying to read stream from body via reader. It was happening even though I was just reading response, I didn't try to modify it in any possible way. Also it wasn't reproducable every time. Only when multiple async requests are processed at the same time. One by one it worked perfectly. And I've found [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/35364).

They mentioned that this bug was introduced from .NET 7 in that discussion. So we tried to update to .NET 8 hoping that it would solve the problem, but it didn't.

So eventually I've found out that built-in logger also has a way to customize it via code, not only options choice what to log and what to ignore. So I tried that. Good news - it doesn't give exception on trying to read body. Bad news - it always returns empty string.

I guess it's either something can still be done or it's just a bug that Microsoft needs to fix. So which one is it?