# Response body empty after updating from Core 2.0 to 3.1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

> UPDATE: If I change return new OkObjectResult(token); to return Ok("test"); then it's not empty.

To use the API you have to call AuthenticateAsync which creates and returns a token.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AuthenticateAsync([FromBody]string apiKey)
    {
        return await StopwatchLogger.LogExecutionTime($"Authenticate user: {apiKey}", async () =>
        {
            EnsureValidLoginRequest(apiKey);

            //Validate user credentials
            AuthenticationInfo authenticationInfo = await _authenticationService.AuthenticateUser(apiKey);
            if (!authenticationInfo.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                throw new RestApiExceptionNoLogging(ErrorCode.AuthenticationInvalidApiKey, "");
            }

            //Login current user and get the created token with claims identifying current user
            Token token = _authenticationService.LoginApiUser(HttpContext, authenticationInfo.SystemUser);

            return new OkObjectResult(token);
        });
    }
```

The token is created correctly and from what I can tell everything is just as before, except the response body becomes empty. No errors are thrown.

EDIT:
Adding startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    private const string LogText = "An error occurred during startup.";

    private readonly List<Exception> _exceptions = new List<Exception>();

    private IWebHostEnvironment _HostingEnvironment;
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        _HostingEnvironment = env;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="services"></param>
    /// <remarks>Is called before Configure</remarks>
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        try
        {
            if (_exceptions.Any())
            {
                return;
            }
            // Add framework services. See configuration class (implementing IConfigureOptions<MvcOptions>) for specific implementation details.
            services.AddApiVersioning(o =>
            {
                o.ReportApiVersions = true;
                o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            });

            // Adds services required for using options.
            services.AddOptions();
            services.AddLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.AddConsole();
                logging.AddDebug();
            });

            //Add scoped services (New service for every request)
            services.AddScoped<IJwtBearerService, JwtBearerService>();
            services.AddScoped<IApiAuthService, ApiAuthService>();
            services.AddScoped<ILoggingService, LoggingService>();


            services.AddScoped<IResponseDatabaseLogger, ResponseDatabaseLogger>();
            services.AddScoped<IRequestDatabaseLogger, RequestDatabaseLogger>();

            services.AddScoped<IAuthService, AuthService>();
            services.AddScoped<IOrderService, OrderService>();
            services.AddScoped<IApiOrderService, ApiOrderService>();
            services.AddScoped<IHaikomService, HaikomService>();

            services.AddDbContext<LoggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
            services.AddDbContext<OrderContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
            services.AddDbContext<AuthContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

            ////Add application setting as options to enable dependency injection for settings
            services.Configure<Mediacreator.RestApi.Models.AuthenticationModel.Options.AuthenticationOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Get the setting from environment variable or user secret.
                // For more info: https://blogcarlosperez.com/2016/05/24/user-secrets/ eller http://asp.net-hacker.rocks/2016/07/11/user-secrets-in-aspnetcore.html
                options.JwtEncryptionSigningSecret = Configuration["Tokens:Key"];
                options.Audience = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"];
                options.Issuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"];
            });


            services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
            services.AddSingleton<IResponseFileLogger, ResponseFileLogger>();
            services.AddSingleton<IRequestFileLogger, RequestFileLogger>();

            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            // Resolve the services from the service provider
            var jwtBearerService = sp.GetService<IJwtBearerService>();

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = jwtBearerService.CreateTokenValidationParameters(Configuration["Tokens:Key"]);
            });

            services.Configure<IISOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.ForwardClientCertificate = false;
                options.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
            });

            services.AddMvc(options =>
            {
                //The services should only support JSON as output format for avoiding supporting for example XML
                //By specifying this property, the client will get a 406 error message if the accept header is for example "Accept: application/xml".
                options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;

                options.EnableEndpointRouting = false;

                //Enable events executed before, and after an action has been executed.
                options.Filters.Add(typeof(ActionFilter));

                //Make all controllers be protected by authorization
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();

                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
         }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _exceptions.Add(ex);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app"></param>
    /// <param name="env"></param>
    /// <param name="loggerFactory"></param>
    /// <remarks>Is called after ConfigureServices</remarks>
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        ILogger logger = null;

        try
        {
            NLog.LogManager.LoadConfiguration("NLog.config");

            loggerFactory.EnsureApiLoggersExists();
            logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger(this.GetType());
            logger.LogInformation($"Current environment: {env.EnvironmentName}");

            //Check if any exceptions occurred during startup
            if (_exceptions.Any())
            {
                //Terminate the pipeline and return a response to the client
                app.Run(async httpContext =>
                {
                    await ExceptionHandler.HandleExceptionWriteErrorResponse(logger, httpContext, _exceptions.First(), LogText);
                });
            }

            //Important to add this middleware first as exceptions in other middleware are also to be caught
            app.UseCustomExceptionHandler();

            //Important to add this middleware before UseMvc is added as the middleware component otherwise may not be called for all requests.
            app.UseRequestLogger();
            app.UseResponseLogger();
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Terminate the pipeline and return a response to the client
            app.Run(async httpContext =>
            {
                await ExceptionHandler.HandleExceptionWriteErrorResponse(logger, httpContext, ex, LogText);
            });
        }
    }


}
```

I had to change IHostingEnvironment to IWebHostEnvironment. There were some changes to logging, I had to add options.EnableEndpointRouting = false to the MVC options.  There were a few more things that I can't remember from the top of my head.

EDIT 2, adding logging of response:

```
public class ResponseLogger : MiddlewareBase
{
    private readonly IResponseFileLogger _IResponseLogger;
    public ResponseLogger(RequestDelegate nextRequestDelegate, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IResponseFileLogger respLogger) : base(nextRequestDelegate, loggerFactory)
    {
        _IResponseLogger = respLogger;
    }
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        //Adds an identifier to the response headers. The identifier is used for connecting a response to log posts for corresponding requests and responses.
        context.AddTraceIdentifierToResponseHeaders();

        //The original response body needs to be stored locally as it can not be rewind after reading and logging it.
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37855384/log-httpresponse-body-for-asp-net-core-1-0-rest-api/38275942#38275942

        using (var responseBodyBufferStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            //Store the original body stream in a local variable
            var responseBodyStream = context.Response.Body;

            try
            {
                //Replace the context response with the newly created buffer as the original stream is not readable.
                context.Response.Body = responseBodyBufferStream;

                //Invoke the rest of the pipeline
                await InvokeNextDelegate(context);

                //Reset the buffer so the content can be read
                responseBodyBufferStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                //Create a stream reader to be able to read the response
                using (var bufferStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseBodyBufferStream))
                {
                    //Read the body from the stream
                    string responseBody = await bufferStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync();

                    //Reset the buffer
                    responseBodyBufferStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                    //Copy the content to the original stream and put it back
                    await responseBodyBufferStream.CopyToAsync(responseBodyStream);

                    //var responseFileLogger = new ResponseFileLogger(LoggerFactory, context, responseBody);
                    _IResponseLogger.Log(context, responseBody);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                //Ensure original body stream is is written back to the response body even if an exception occurs in another middleware.
                context.Response.Body = responseBodyStream;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried commenting out the response logged code to see if that was part of the problem but seemed to make no difference from what I could tell.

EDIT 3, adding output from request:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://localhost:5000/api/v1.0/authentication application/json; charset=utf-8 41
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {action = "Authenticate", controller = "Authentication"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.IActionResult] AuthenticateAsync(System.String) on controller Mediacreator.RestApi.Controllers.AuthenticationController (CoreRestApi).
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.1.1 initialized 'LoggingContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (70ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (Size = 4000), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (Size = 4000), @p3='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p4='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p5='?' (DbType = Int32), @p6='?' (Size = 4000), @p7='?' (DbType = Int64), @p8='?' (Size = 4000), @p9='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      INSERT INTO [ApiLogs] ([Action], [RemoteAddress], [RequestData], [RequestDateUtc], [ResponseDateUtc], [ResponseStatusCode], [Status], [SystemUserId], [TraceIdentifier], [Url])
      VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9);
      SELECT [Id]
      FROM [ApiLogs]
      WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [Id] = scope_identity();
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure[10403]
      Entity Framework Core 3.1.1 initialized 'AuthContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer' with options: None
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (22ms) [Parameters=[@__apiKey_0='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[ApiKey], [t].[Deleted], [t].[Description], [t].[IsActive], [t].[Password], [t].[Permissions], [t].[Username], [t0].[SystemUserId], [t0].[UserRoleId], [t0].[Id], [t0].[Description], [t0].[Name]
      FROM (
          SELECT TOP(2) [s].[Id], [s].[ApiKey], [s].[Deleted], [s].[Description], [s].[IsActive], [s].[Password], [s].[Permissions], [s].[Username]
          FROM [SystemUsers] AS [s]
          WHERE [s].[ApiKey] = @__apiKey_0
      ) AS [t]
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT [s0].[SystemUserId], [s0].[UserRoleId], [u].[Id], [u].[Description], [u].[Name]
          FROM [SystemUserRole] AS [s0]
          INNER JOIN [UserRoles] AS [u] ON [s0].[UserRoleId] = [u].[Id]
      ) AS [t0] ON [t].[Id] = [t0].[SystemUserId]
      ORDER BY [t].[Id], [t0].[SystemUserId], [t0].[UserRoleId], [t0].[Id]
info: Mediacreator.RestApi.Services.Authentication.ApiAuthService[0]
      User with ApiKey <xxx> authenticated
info: Mediacreator.RestApi.Services.Authentication.ApiAuthService[0]
      Token created for user '<yyy>' (5). Token is valid '3600' seconds
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (20ms) [Parameters=[@__logId_0='?' (DbType = Int64)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SELECT TOP(2) [a].[Id], [a].[Action], [a].[RemoteAddress], [a].[RequestData], [a].[RequestDateUtc], [a].[ResponseDateUtc], [a].[ResponseStatusCode], [a].[Status], [a].[SystemUserId], [a].[TraceIdentifier], [a].[Url]
      FROM [ApiLogs] AS [a]
      WHERE [a].[Id] = @__logId_0
info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
      Executed DbCommand (20ms) [Parameters=[@p3='?' (DbType = Int64), @p0='?' (DbType = DateTime2), @p1='?' (DbType = Int32), @p2='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      UPDATE [ApiLogs] SET [ResponseDateUtc] = @p0, [ResponseStatusCode] = @p1, [Status] = @p2
      WHERE [Id] = @p3;
      SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor[1]
      Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'Mediacreator.RestApi.Models.AuthenticationModel.Entities.Token'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action Mediacreator.RestApi.Controllers.AuthenticationController.AuthenticateAsync (CoreRestApi) in 8305.5034ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished in 11069.4992ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

EDIT 4: Adding Token class

```
public class Token
{
    public readonly string access_token;
    public readonly string token_type = Constants.TokenTypeBearer;
    public readonly int expires_in;

    public Token(string encodedJsonWebToken, int expiresInSeconds)
    {
        access_token = encodedJsonWebToken;
        expires_in = expiresInSeconds;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your Startup.cs file? Core 3.1 involved some adjustments in startup that could impact the controllers. Thanks.

Comment: What is Http Status? What are the Http Headers being sent back in the response? How do you know the "body" is empty? Can you post screen shots of the developer tools so we can see the exact nature of the response?

Comment: @Darkonekt I log the response: 2020-01-27 14:41:59.5029 - 9|0HLT35MFFPJ9E|INFO: Response:
    TraceIdentifier: 0HLT35MFFPJ9E:00000001
    Status code: 200
    Header - WWWAuthenticate: 
    Header - Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Response body: {}

Comment: Log the response how? We will need to see that too. We need more information

Comment: @Darkonekt Added the response logging.

Comment: Can you show the ASP.NET Core logging output for this request?

Comment: Why easy when you can make it complicated.... No need for custom rewind code, just use [EnableBuffering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequestrewindextensions.enablebuffering?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for that one request

Comment: @poke Not sure there is anything interesting in the request: 2020-01-27 14:34:23.2968 - 9|0HLT35MFFPJ9E|INFO: Request:
    TraceIdentifier: 0HLT35MFFPJ9E:00000001
    Client IP: ::1
    Request path: localhost:5000/api/v1.0/authentication
    QueryString: 
    Content length: 41
    Content type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    Request method: POST
    HeaderAuthorization: 
    Request body: "sensored"

Comment: There should be a lot more in the logs. Increase the log verbosity if you don’t see anything. Note that I am not interested in your request/response message but at the application flow on the server.

Comment: @poke Added output with verbosity set to detailed.

Comment: Update: If I send in an invalid API key I get a 401 error and the response body is not empty.

Comment: Also if I change return new OkObjectResult(token); to return Ok("test"); then it's not empty. At least one step closer...

Comment: Rather do `return Ok(token)` instead of `return new OkObjectResult(token)`.

Comment: My guess is that your `Token` (would help if you posted the class definition or linked to the appropriate MSDN page) is either null or is being serialized to an empty string by the runtime.

Comment: @IanKemp I have added the Token class to the question.

Comment: @IanKemp Shouldn't be a difference using Ok or OkObjectResult, I have also tried both now with no difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason it was not working was as @Ian Kemp suggested that the serialization of my Token class wasn't working. I read they added a new Serialization with System.Text.Json in Core 3.0 and for some reason it's not working with

```
public class Token
{
   public readonly string access_token;
   public readonly string token_type = Constants.TokenTypeBearer;
   public readonly int expires_in;

   public Token(string encodedJsonWebToken, int expiresInSeconds)
   {
      access_token = encodedJsonWebToken;
      expires_in = expiresInSeconds;
   }
}
```

So I decided to try Newtonsoft and now it works as before.

Solution was to add this to ConfigureServices in Startup.cs

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```